# Adding Multiple Event Listeners in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm trying to add event listeners to multiple elements with the same class on the chrome extension popup. The event listeners are triggered with 'click' and open a new tab. My popup.html file looks something like this

```
...
<li class="listing">List1</li>
<li class="listing">List2</li>
...
<scripts src="popup.js"></script>
...
```

Whenever the list tags are clicked, they should open a new tab, but this never happens. Here is what my popup.js file looks like

```
function openLink(end){
    const term = end.trim().split(" ").join("+");
    chrome.tabs.create({url:`https://google.com/search?q=${term}`});
}

var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('listing');
for( var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
      inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function() { openLink("meep") } );
   })
}
```

The openLink function should work fine, it's just the event listeners. I have also tried leaving the "DOMContentLoaded" event listener outside the for loop but nothing happened. Any fixes?

Comment: Remove the line with DOMContentLoaded and its corresponding }), no need for that because judging by the first fragment of html your script already runs when DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was fixed. Rather than adding an event listener, I had to add the .onclick event on the creation of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the loop inside the function, to collect the input fields and add the event listeners after the dom has loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
  const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('listing');
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {openLink("meep")});
})
```

Comment: Did not fix anything. Even without the DOMContentLoaded listener, I can add an event listener to a single Id. It seems I can add event listeners to classes through a for loop inside the DevTools Console, but not in popup.js. Very strange

Answer (score 0):

You Can Write

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.listening')
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener("click", function() {
    openLink("meep")
}))
```

it will return a node list so you can use forEach loop to add the event listener to each element in the list